# Metaprogramming member checker doesn't work with function members returning a type with a base class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have implemented a metaprogramming member checker like this:

```
//Declare a metaprogramming test to check if a class has a member
//of a given signature and a certain name
#define DECL_hasMember(MEMBER)                                                  \
/* Check if T has member MEMBER M is a pointer to member of T type (T::*) */    \
template <typename T, typename M>                                               \
class hasMember_##MEMBER {                                                      \
    private:                                                                    \
        typedef char passed[1];                                                 \
        typedef char failed[2];                                                 \
                                                                                \
        template <typename U, U> struct reallyHas;                              \
                                                                                \
        template <typename C> static passed& test(reallyHas<M, &C::MEMBER>*);   \
        template <typename C> static failed& test(...);                         \
                                                                                \
        hasMember_##MEMBER()=delete;                                            \
    public:                                                                     \
        static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(passed);   \
}
```

I've tested this in many situation and the checker works fine in most situations,

Now I am implementing a Finite State Machine using the curiously recurring template pattern, which has a map associating states to functions of the derived class. I want this derived class to have a member called buildFSM, creating said map. I want to enforce this using static assert, to have nicer compiler errors. But the metaprogramming checker doesn't seem to be able to detect `desc_t`

(I've tried to replicate the situation in a simpler scenario for the sake of the question, but couldn't get it to fail in a different context)

```
DECL_hasMember(buildFSM);

template<class Executor_T, typename State_T = uint32_t, typename ... Args>
class FSM
{
    public:
        typedef State_T state_t;
        typedef FSM<Executor_T, State_T, Args...> fsm_t;

    protected:
        /* returns the next state */
        typedef state_t (Executor_T::*handler_t)(Args...);
        /* holds all the states */
        struct desc_t : private std::map<state_t, handler_t> {
            friend fsm_t;
            void addState(const state_t&, handler_t);

            using std::map<state_t, handler_t>::size;
            using std::map<state_t, handler_t>::empty;
        };

    private:
        /* Implementation must implement buildFSM returning a desc_t that initializes this */
        static desc_t states;

        static_assert(hasMember_buildFSM<Executor_T, desc_t(Executor_T::*)()>::value,
            "Implementing class must provide desc_t buildFSM() function member.");

    /* [...] */
};

//Delegate the initialization of states to the derived class
template<class E, typename S, typename ... A>
decltype(FSM<E, S, A...>::states) FSM<E, S, A...>::states= std::move(E::buildFSM());

struct test : public FSM<test> {
    fsm_t::desc_t buildFSM() {
        return fsm_t::desc_t();
    }
};
```

As I said before, the static assert fails, i.e. it can't detect `test::buildFSM`. The problem is in `desc_t`, because if I change it to another type, the test passes just fine. If I modify `desc_t` so it doesn't derive `std::map`, the test also passes. Why does this happen? Is there anything I can do to make this work in this case? I know an alternative would be just having the map as a member instead of a base class, but I don't understand why this happens.

I'm in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I'm also in Visual Studio 2015 and this crashed my compiler. I'm not surprised anymore.

Comment: This doesn't compile in Clang or GCC, which is unsurprising; at the time of instantiation of `FSM<test>`, `test` is an incomplete type, yet your `static_assert` inspects its members, which, of course, fails.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout: [Member detector](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector)

Here is some code to detect member functions:

```
#include <iostream>

// single argument and return type
#define DECL_hasMemberRetArg(MEMBER)                                          \
template<typename T, typename RESULT, typename ARG1>                          \
class Detect_RetArg_##MEMBER                                                  \
{                                                                             \
    template <typename U, RESULT (U::*)(ARG1)> struct Check;                  \
    template <typename U> static char func(Check<U, &U::MEMBER> *);           \
    template <typename U> static int func(...);                               \
  public:                                                                     \
    typedef Detect_RetArg_##MEMBER type;                                      \
    enum { value = sizeof(func<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };                      \
}

// two arguments and return type
#define DECL_hasMemberRetArgArg(MEMBER)                                       \
template<typename T, typename RESULT, typename ARG1, typename ARG2>           \
class Detect_RetArgArg_##MEMBER                                               \
{                                                                             \
    template <typename U, RESULT (U::*)(ARG1, ARG2)> struct Check;            \
    template <typename U> static char func(Check<U, &U::MEMBER> *);           \
    template <typename U> static int func(...);                               \
  public:                                                                     \
    typedef Detect_RetArgArg_##MEMBER type;                                   \
    enum { value = sizeof(func<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };                      \
}

class a_t
{
  char get(int);
  char put(int,long);
};

struct b_t
{
  char get(int);
  char put(int,long);
};

struct c_t : public b_t
{
};

DECL_hasMemberRetArg(get);
DECL_hasMemberRetArgArg(put);

int main()
{
  std::cout << Detect_RetArg_get<a_t, char, int>::value << "\n";          // 0
  std::cout << Detect_RetArgArg_put<a_t, char, int, long>::value << "\n"; // 0
  std::cout << Detect_RetArg_get<b_t, char, int>::value << "\n";          // 1
  std::cout << Detect_RetArgArg_put<b_t, char, int, long>::value << "\n"; // 1
  std::cout << Detect_RetArg_get<c_t, char, int>::value << "\n";          // 0
  std::cout << Detect_RetArgArg_put<c_t, char, int, long>::value << "\n"; // 0
  return 0;
}
```

The template cannot see the base class members.